# How do I avoid creating a session?

Tags: java, apache-flex, session, session-cookies, blazeds

My setup is as follows

- A main application servlet accessible under /myApp/mainServlet/
- A little "hand made" soap proxy that adds security headers (usernames, passwords) to soap calls coming from a client
- A Flex client that talks to the main servlet (through a BlazeDS interface), and sends some soap calls to a third party through this soap proxy

The flex client has a session id which is set when it first talks to the main servlet and it returns a HTTP header such as "Set-Cookie: "JSESSION: something; Path=/myApp". This cookie is then sent the the server to inform of which session the client is associated to.

The problem is that the little soap proxy *also* returns a cookie with a session id (for each call made through it) - and the Flex client then uses these cookies when talking to the main servlet. These other session ids are unknown to it, and then of course nothing works ...

I do not want a session cookie to be returned from the soap proxy, and I have verified that the problem would be solved by doing so by telling an Apache front-end to strip all "Set-Cookie" headers coming from the soap proxy. Unfortunately (due to some setup restrictions), this is not a way I can go in production, and so I will need to fix it programmatically.

**How can I make the servlet not try to set any session ids?** I believe I have seen ways of telling Jetty (the app server) not to send sessions ids, but that would also affect the main servlet's ability to do so as well, and is also not portable.

The proxy servlet is a very basic Spring Controller (just implementing the interface), so basically just a bare bone servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the cookie can be done with `res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", null);`

**Edit:** It is good to know, that this removes **all** cookies, since they are all set in the same header.

I recommend that you don't do it in your servlet, a Filter is better, because it's less intrusive, something like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    try
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
    finally 
    {
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", null);
    }
}
```

This solution is inspired by [this article](http://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful) at randomcoder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kiril! BTW - are you implicitly saying that a session is always created in a Java Servlet Container? I am asking because I am unsure of what the spec says. Who is responsible for making the session?

Comment: @oligofren You create the session with `responce.getSession()`. You say you have a "SOAP proxy", how exactly does it proxy, and where to? Could the actual place that the SOAP response is coming from, be setting the cookie?

Comment: Good point! I never thought of that, but yes: it redirects to a Axis service (running on Glassfish), and that could of course set the session id. After some experimentation with a bare bones servlet (code in  ch-simple-web/simple-webapp in http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip) I can now see that a basic servlet is not returning a JSESSIONID - unless I do a getSession(). So you are indeed right - the session cookie is from the server I am proxying the requests to!